# Is it possible to run one emacs but from two terminals?

Tags: terminal-emacs

I was thinking about how I work normally on services.  Where I might write code in an editor via Emacs in a terminal view, and in another terminal run the code, and yet still in another view `tail` the log.

I'd like to do something similar but with Emacs.  For instance, write some code in elisp which updates a buffer that's something like a log, but I'd like to put that log/view on another window in another terminal altogether, but controlled from one Emacs.  Is this possible?  If so how?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this would be addressed by running Emacs in daemon mode. For instance, when I start up I run:

```
emacs --daemon
```

Then I can start a new client with

```
emacsclient -nw my/file
```

And in another terminal open a client with no file with

```
emacsclient -nw
```

(`-nw` = use console rather than opening a GUI window, but also avoids needing to provide a file.)

Both clients share the same set of buffers; it's like opening a new frame in a GUI version of Emacs.

I have an idiosyncratic config for server mode, but I believe this will work as described out of the box, as it were. You can read in more detail at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon

Comment: I think this might work.  Do you know if `other-window` command takes into account windows in another terminal?  Or if there is an alternative command that does so?

Comment: I'm 99% sure you need your window manager to switch between separate terminal windows.  When Emacs is running in a terminal, I don't imagine it has any control over the GUI environment outside of that terminal.  (You might be able to teach Emacs to talk to your window manager in order to invoke a "switch to another terminal" command, but that would depend on whether your WM provided such a command in the first place.)